# Update-Package -reinstall does not reinstall package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a larger project, which resides in multiple repositories. The projects reference each other using nuget packages. I'm currently working on a larger architectural change, which requires modifying multiple packages at once. To keep them in sync i use a local folder (`~\Packages`) as temporary feed. All builds of a package will have the same version number, so i have to reinstall rather than update the packages to use the current version in the referencing projects.

Hoever when i run

```
Update-Package -reinstall -IncludePrereleases
```

None of my packaes is reinstalled (as far as i can tell) and the output says:

> No package updates are available from the current package source for project .

The above output also appears, when i run

```
Get-Package -Updates
```

I tried setting the package source to only the local folder and back to all, but i didn't made a difference. I tried adding the local feed to the target projects nuget.config, but the result stayed the same. Of couse i tries rebooting VisualStudio as well my pc.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.1.0 Preview 1.0.
The project is an SDK format csproj.

I didn't test on other versions or project formats.

Comment: are you sure you need "IncludePrereleases" when you only reinstall ? i thought you only need this for updates. try running "update-package -reinstall" without "-includeprereleases"

Comment: @D.J. I tried both with `-IncludePrerelease` and without. Since the package version is currently a prerelease i thought that might be the reason the package is not updated

Comment: What does `get-package -Updates` show? (Ie. just get what the package manager thinks is available for update)

Comment: @Richard The same error message as above.

Comment: @Pretasoc, could you please have a try with a new solution and check if this issue persists or not? Now the VS 2019 RTM version is released and you can also test it with this latest VS version.